# Identify an Unusual USB Port

Tags: usb, ups, connector

The back of our APC Smart-UPS 2000 has a USB port so that it can be monitored from a server it supplies.

However, this USB port doesn't appear to be a standard USB connector. It looks a little like an RJ-45 connector, I tried an Ethernet cable in case the port was just mislabeled but that didn't fit either.

[image: Strange USB port]

Can anyone help identify the type of USB it is?

Comment: @JakeGould It's likely a legacy format rather than a licensing issue. RJ-45 connectors for serial ports have been around a long time. I know as recently as 2010 I had Cisco gear on my desk that used an RJ-45 to serial adapter to get a console connection. This question should help clarify https://serverfault.com/questions/629436/why-is-rj45-db9-console-cable-still-used-when-all-the-latest-computer-do-not-ha

Comment: Technically that *is* an RJ-45. It just happens to be wired for USB instead of Ethernet.

Comment: I bet someone got a really nice bonus for that feature. (To quote Raymond Chen)

Comment: Fun fact : USB male fit into a RJ45 slot. So when our user says "yeah I plugged it in" don't trust him...

Comment: @Freiheit: For console cables, RJ-45 might be quite intentional since a [rollover cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_cable) greatly simplifies serial connections (no need to distinguish between regular and null-modem cables or use DTE/DCE gender changers, and of course no need for a massive DB-9 port).

Comment: @Freiheit RJ45 serial connectors are *very* common on enterprise network gear.  My (freshly bought) Ubiquiti EdgeRouter Lite has an RJ45 serial connector.

Comment: @chrylis, well, if you trust Wikipedia, [that's technically _not_ an RJ45](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack#RJ45), but just a quite similar-looking modular connector.

Comment: @Goufalite That's way too real. I tried debugging a wireless issue of a client through the phone once. Turned out that the client had a wireless usb dongle plugged in to the RJ-45 port. Needless to say I was stunned.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

That is a port for a [UPS Communications Cable Simple Signalling - USB to RJ45 cable](http://www.apc.com/shop/us/en/products/UPS-Communications-Cable-Simple-Signalling-USB-to-RJ45/P-AP9827) for connecting to a computer. The cable is included with many compatible APC devices.

[image: UPS Communications Cable Simple Signalling - USB to RJ45 cable]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69776/discussion-on-answer-by-steven-identify-an-unusual-usb-port).

Answer (score 65):

That is an APC cable by Schneider Electric cable P/N  AP9827

[https://www.amazon.com/APC-AP9827-USB-cable/dp/B0002WYJSU](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002WYJSU)

It looks like half an Ethernet cable with just four wires in 1 3 5 6
[image]

APC's user manual from one type of UPS is downloadable at:
http://www.apc.com/salestools/JGNY-9X784R/JGNY-9X784R_R0_EN.pdf

And an excerpt with that connector is:

[image]

Comment: Very funny the fact that the DSub-9 is often used for serials but cannot be used with normal cables and the RJ45 is totally seldomly used for USB. Insane hardware of the past.

Comment: @eckes insane hardware of _now_ - this is pretty much standard on UPSs.

Comment: The UPS might be sold to a few customers that specify connectors to physically lock - which RJxx does and USBxx does not. Also, "generic" USB cables might be undesirable in environments where eg flammability standards are to be adhered to... OR, there are two versions (one with another serial, another with a USB port) sharing the same faceplate...

Comment: @eckes I had to wire a cable for a UPS years ago. From memory the circuit was just 4 resistors and swapping some wires in a RS232 cable. The reason is that the D-Sub9 port on a UPS is a control port, not a serial comms port, and D-Sub9 is just a generic connector design, not specifically for RS232 serial comms, even though pre-USB it became the most common serial connector for PCs. I haven't worked with UPS for years, but I had the impression everything had been redesigned to use standard serial comms. Interesting to see that the old designs persist on some devices